# What does a single * without identifier mean in the Python3 functions?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

What does a single * without identifier mean in the Python function arguments?
Here is an example that works with Python3.2:

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, *, shapename, **kwds):
        self.shapename = shapename
        super().__init__(**kwds)
```

For me the star after the self is strange.

I have found it here (from row 46):
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577720-how-to-use-super-effectively/

UPDATE: Later [also / was added to the argument list of Python functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735311/what-does-the-slash-mean-when-help-is-listing-method-signatures/24735582#24735582). You might want to understand them in pair.

Comment: Extra points for the one who points to the PEP ;) (i remember reading a fragment a PEP describing this, but i can't remember where, or what it was, **/me goes back to google**)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The lone `*` indicates that all following arguments are keyword-only arguments, that is, they can only be provided using their name, not as positional argument.

See [PEP 3102](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) for further details.

Comment: In other words: `shapename` has to be explicitly added when creating a new `Shape` object, like `Shape(shapename='Circle')`