# What does the slash mean when help() is listing method signatures?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, introspection

What does the `/` mean in Python 3.4's `help` output for `range` before the closing parenthesis?

```
>>> help(range)
Help on class range in module builtins:

class range(object)
 |  range(stop) -> range object
 |  range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object
 |  
 |  Return a virtual sequence of numbers from start to stop by step.
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __contains__(self, key, /)
 |      Return key in self.
 |  
 |  __eq__(self, value, /)
 |      Return self==value.

                                        ...
```

Answer (score 311, accepted):

It signifies the end of the [*positional only* parameters](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0436/#functions-with-positional-only-parameters), parameters you *cannot* use as keyword parameters. Before Python 3.8, such parameters could only be specified in the C API.

It means the `key` argument to `__contains__` can only be passed in by position (`range(5).__contains__(3)`), not as a keyword argument (`range(5).__contains__(key=3)`), something you *can* do with positional arguments in pure-python functions.

Also see the [Argument Clinic](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/clinic.html) documentation:

> To mark all parameters as positional-only in Argument Clinic, add a `/` on a line by itself after the last parameter, indented the same as the parameter lines.

and the (very recent addition to) the [Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-does-the-slash-in-the-parameter-list-of-a-function-mean):

> A slash in the argument list of a function denotes that the parameters prior to it are positional-only. Positional-only parameters are the ones without an externally-usable name. Upon calling a function that accepts positional-only parameters, arguments are mapped to parameters based solely on their position.

The syntax is now part of the Python language specification, [as of version 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters), see [PEP 570 – *Python Positional-Only Parameters*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/). Before PEP 570, the syntax was already reserved for possible future inclusion in Python, see [PEP 457 - *Syntax For Positional-Only Parameters*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0457/).

Positional-only parameters can lead to cleaner and clearer APIs, make pure-Python implementations of otherwise C-only modules more consistent and easier to maintain, and because positional-only parameters require very little processing, they lead to faster Python code.

Comment: An interesting side effect is that the names of positional only arguments don't conflict with `**kwargs`, which can be useful for functional programming or decorating functions where the decorator argument names might conflict with the decorated function arguments.

Comment: You explained what, not why! Should mention why this is useful - and as @hugovdberg said above, it's about not conflicting with `**kwargs`

Comment: @MarcosPereira: the question asked for *what*: *What does the slash mean in help() output?*.

Comment: "Why" is an entirely separate question (one I've never seen an entirely convincing answer to).

Comment: @MarcosPereira: I am not even sure what hugovdberg is saying there, *not conflicting with `kwargs`* did not come up in the discussions around this PEP. See the [motivation section of PEP 570](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/#motivation) for the documented reasons for the addition of the syntax.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did not say it was the primary motivation, but it does help in cases like this: https://gist.github.com/Hugovdberg/98e42f07b03c6f6bfc07e139bac2af8a The example is a little contrived in this case, but patterns like this come up in functional programming every once in a while.

Comment: @hugovdberg: I was confused there for a while, but you are talking about the `func` **parameter** in the signature of `delay_call2()`, where a call on line 50 works because the `func` (keyword) *argument* won't conflict with the `func` parameter. Yes, this is a happy side-effect of the syntax, before you'd have to use `*args` and unpack the argument assigned to the `func` parameter from that. Generally: the names in the function signature are parameters, the values passed in in a call expression are the arguments. Makes it easier to talk about the syntax used in the two sides of calls.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, that's indeed what I meant to say.

Answer (score 94):

I asked this question myself. :) Found out that `/` was originally proposed by Guido in [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2012-March/014364.html).

> Alternative proposal: how about using '/' ? It's kind of the opposite
>   of '*' which means "keyword argument", and '/' is not a new character.

Then his proposal [won](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2012-March/014417.html).

> Heh. If that's true, my '/' proposal wins:
>
> ```
>  def foo(pos_only, /, pos_or_kw, *, kw_only): ...
> ```

---

I think the very relevant document covering this is [PEP 570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/#positional-only-parameters).
Where recap section looks nice.

> Recap
>
> The use case will determine which parameters to use in the function definition:
>
> ```
>  def f(pos1, pos2, /, pos_or_kwd, *, kwd1, kwd2):
> ```
>
> As guidance:
>
> Use positional-only if names do not matter or have no meaning, and there are only a few arguments which will always be passed in the same order.
>      Use keyword-only when names have meaning and the function definition is more understandable by being explicit with names.

---

If the function ends with `/`

```
def foo(p1, p2, /)
```

This means all functional arguments are positional.

Comment: Choosing the `/` token, because "it's the inverse operation of `*`" shows, that Python is just a little bit crazy. It's a kind of synesthesia.

Comment: `def f(pos1, pos2, /, pos_or_kwd, *, kwd1, kwd2)` is certainly the best and concise way to remember both ... both what? not arguments, not keywords, not operators... ah it's also in the PEP... both markers. At least if you remember the standard arguments were "pos_or_kwd" before the introduction of the markers.

Comment: +1 for `def foo(pos_only, /, pos_or_kw, *, kw_only)`, which simply explains the things: `/` and `*` — *a pair of inverse arithmetic operators being used parametrically by Guido* — (optionally) divides an argument list into (at most) three parts.

Answer (score 39):

Forward Slash (/) indicates all arguments prior to it are positional only argument. Positional only arguments feature was added in python 3.8 after [PEP 570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/) was accepted. Initially this notation was defined in [PEP 457 - Notation For Positional-Only Parameters](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0457/)

> Parameters in function definition prior Foraward slash (/) are positional only and parameters followed by slash(/) can be of any kind as per syntax. Where arguments are mapped to positional only parameters solely based on their position upon calling a function. Passing positional-only parameters by keywords(name) is invalid.

Let's take following example

```
def foo(a, b, / , x, y):
   print("positional ", a, b)
   print("positional or keyword", x, y)
```

Here in the above function definition parameters a and b are positional-only, while x or y can be either positional or keyword.

Following function calls are valid

```
foo(40, 20, 99, 39)
foo(40, 3.14, "hello", y="world")
foo(1.45, 3.14, x="hello", y="world")
```

But, following function call is not valid which raises an exception TypeError since a, b are not passed as positional arguments instead passed as keyword

```
foo(a=1.45, b=3.14, x=1, y=4)
```

> TypeError: foo() got some positional-only arguments passed as keyword
> arguments: 'a, b'

Many built in function in python accept positional only arguments where passing arguments by keyword doesn't make sense. For example built-in function **len** accepts only one positional(only) argument, Where calling len as len(obj="hello world")  impairs readability, check help(len).

```
>>> help(len)
Help on built-in function len in module builtins:

len(obj, /)
    Return the number of items in a container.
```

Positional only parameters make underlying c/library functions easy to maintain. It allows parameters names of positional only parameters to be changes in future without risk of breaking client code that uses API

Last but not least, positional only parameters allow us to use their names to be used in variable length keyword arguments. Check following example

```
>>> def f(a, b, /, **kwargs):
...     print(a, b, kwargs)
...
>>> f(10, 20, a=1, b=2, c=3)         # a and b are used in two ways
10 20 {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Positional-only parameters syntax was officially added to python3.8. Checkout [what's new python3.8 - positional only arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters)

PEP Related: [PEP 570 -- Python Positional-Only Parameters](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/)