# What is the meaning of a forward slash "/" in a Python method signature, as shown by help(foo)?

Tags: python, inspection, python-interactive

In the signature returned interactively by `help(foo)`, what is the meaning of a `/`?

```
In [37]: help(object.__eq__)

Help on wrapper_descriptor:

__eq__(self, value, /)
    Return self==value.

In [55]: help(object.__init__)

Help on wrapper_descriptor:

__init__(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
    Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
```

I thought it might be related to keyword-only arguments, but it's not.  When I create my own function with keyword-only arguments, positional and keyword-only arguments are separated by `*` (as expected), not by `/`.  What does the `/` mean?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24735582/860196), the `/` as an argument marks the end of arguments that are positional only (see [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0436/#functions-with-positional-only-parameters)), i.e. arguments you can't use as keyword parameters. In the case of `__eq__(self, value, /)` the slash is at the end, which means that all arguments are marked as positional only while in the case of your `__init__` only self, i.e. nothing, is positional only.

**Edit:**
This was previously only used for built-in functions but [since Python 3.8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/), you can use this in your own functions. The natural companion of `/` is `*` which allows to mark the beginning of keyword-only arguments. [Example using both](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters):

```
# a, b are positional-only
# c, d are positional or keyword
# e, f are keyword-only
def f(a, b, /, c, d, *, e, f):
    print(a, b, c, d, e, f)

# valid call
f(10, 20, 30, d=40, e=50, f=60)

# invalid calls:
f(10, b=20, c=30, d=40, e=50, f=60)   # b cannot be a keyword argument
f(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, f=60)           # e must be a keyword argument
```