# how to understand Python 'help' document

Tags: python

for example

```
>>> help(str)


class str(object)
 |  str(object='') -> str
 |  str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str
 |  
 |  Create a new string object from the given object. If encoding or
 |  errors is specified, then the object must expose a data buffer
 |  that will be decoded using the given encoding and error handler.
 |  Otherwise, returns the result of object.__str__() (if defined)
 |  or repr(object).
 |  encoding defaults to sys.getdefaultencoding().
 |  errors defaults to 'strict'.
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __add__(self, value, /)
 |      Return self+value.
 |  
 |  __contains__(self, key, /)
 |      Return key in self.
 |  
 |  __eq__(self, value, /)
 |      Return self==value.
 |
 |  capitalize(...)
 |      S.capitalize() -> str
```

I guess `func(args[, a[, b]])`
means argument `a` and `b` was optional

What puzzled me was the identity of function

what does `func(...)` mean?
How about `func(arg, arg, /)`  the `/` means?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243832 will help with the "/"

Comment: thanks, I searched for 'python document' 'python help' before asking.. but how about '...'

Comment: `...` is generally used in text to mean that anything can go there.