# What does '/' mean in the following help statement: __init__(self, /, *args, **kwargs)?

Tags: python-3.x

When I execute help(Exception), this is how **init** defined. It seems to me  the '/' has no meaning at all.

Could anybody give me a tip? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of a forward slash "/" in a Python method signature, as shown by help(foo)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243832/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-forward-slash-in-a-python-method-signature-as-show)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: What does the slash mean in the output of help(range)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735311/python-what-does-the-slash-mean-in-the-output-of-helprange)