# Why is the sorted() function saying that it only takes one argument when passing 3 arguments?

Tags: python

I have this simple program that is supposed to sort the array of arrays by the key.

Why is the `sorted()` function saying that it only takes 1 argument, and that I am not providing any?

```
import operator

array = [[1, 6, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
sorted_array = sorted(iterable=array, key=operator.itemgetter(array[0][1]), reverse=True)
print(sorted_array)
```

And the error this gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 4, in <module>
    sorted_array = sorted(iterable=array, key=operator.itemgetter(array[0][1]), reverse=True)
TypeError: sorted expected 1 argument, got 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to give you a clear and detailed explanation:

There are 2 problems:

1. `iterable` is not a named parameter
2. `itemgetter` syntax is wrong

**1 - Iterable:**

This is the definition of the `sorted` function (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):
`sorted(iterable, *, key=None, reverse=False)`

Perhaps you thought that `iterable` is a named parameter, but it isn't. The named parameters are `key` and `reverse` (they have the equal sign (=) after their names).

So you don't have to write `iterable=something`. You just have to give an iterable data structure, so in your example that's the variable named `array`:

```
sorted_array = sorted(array,...)
```

***Update**: See @Tomerikoo answer for the exact reason why this didn't work in this case.*

**2 - Itemgetter:**
You can't write `itemgetter(array[0][1])`, you just have to give the indexes of the elements, so as @Ajay wrote in his comment, you could write this instead:

```
itemgetter(0,1)
```

But if you really want to sort by `array[0][1]`, you should use a lambda function as  @Ajay wrote too.

**All in one:**

```
from operator import itemgetter

array = [[1,6,3], [4,5,6]]
sorted_array = sorted(array, key=itemgetter(0,1), reverse=True)
print(sorted_array)
```

**Output:**

```
[[4, 5, 6], [1, 6, 3]]
```

Answer (score 8):

Your confusion is justified. The error:

```
TypeError: sorted expected 1 argument, got 0
```

is a bit confusing to begin with. What it actually means is:

```
sorted expected 1 [positional] argument, got 0
```

Looking at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#sorted), the signature is:

```py
sorted(iterable, *, key=None, reverse=False)
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301967/bare-asterisk-in-function-arguments), a bare `*` in a function's signature means that all following arguments must be ***named***. That doesn't say anything about the preceding arguments.

When printing `help(sorted)` in an interactive shell gives the more accurate signature:

```py
sorted(iterable, /, *, key=None, reverse=False)
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243832/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-forward-slash-in-a-python-method-signature-as-show), a `/` in a function's signature means that all preceding arguments must be ***positional***, i.e. ***not*** named, which now explains the error. You just need to pass the array as a positional argument:

```
sorted_array = sorted(array, key=..., reverse=True)
```

Please refer to [@Rivers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66930842/6045800) for the correct use of `itemgetter` as the key.

---

I have reported this documentation issue on the [official Python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue43713).

Comment: What's the logic behind now being able to say `iterable = array` in the function call for `sorted`? In general, why would the developer not allow a certain argument to be named in the call?

Comment: This is just my personal view - as with the sorted example, the named arguments are like "settings". What key tonuse, should it be reversed etc. It makes sense and is more readable to have them named (only). The caller can omit some, use whatever order etc. Tne first argument is the input list. It should always come first. To me that makes *some* sense. There must be some SO question disccusing this that I will to to find later