# Single '*' and '/' as a parameter in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know what the star operator does depending on its context.
However i keep seeing a solo '*' as a parameter in function definitions and im confused as to what it does...

Why does this work and what does it even do.
I thought you would have had to follow it up with the name of the tuple you want to store the undefined amount of arguments in so you can adress it.

On a similar note i also sometimes see a solo '/' as a parameter when i use the help() built-in function to quickly see what another function does. What is the purpose of it in this context?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

help(dataclass)
```

[image: Help on dataclass function]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301967/bare-asterisk-in-function-arguments  (for the first part)

Comment: If there's more than just one part, it should be multiple separate questions. "Too broad" is a close reason for a reason.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243832/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-forward-slash-in-a-python-method-signature-as-show  (for the second part too)

Comment: Also: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) -- going forward, paste the _text_ of `help()` output (or other textual content integral to the question) instead of taking a screenshot of it.