# What is the extra '/' argument shown in python3 help() output for many of the functions in the math module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I noticed earlier that when you call help on functions like `math.pow` or `math.sqrt` or most of the other functions in math (not all though). I can't seem to find any information about what this means, since its not present in the online docs and these functions don't accept an extra argument. Does anyone know what this means?

Example of what happens when calling help on `math.pow`:

```
>>> help(math.pow)
Help on built-in function pow in module math:

pow(x, y, /)
    Return x**y (x to the power of y).
```

I expected that the signature would be `pow(x, y)` since those are the only 2 arguments accepted. However this `/` argument is present as well.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is the meaning of a forward slash "/" in a Python method signature, as shown by help(foo)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243832/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-forward-slash-in-a-python-method-signature-as-show). Basically it's marking the end of positional arguments.

Comment: I believe it means the arguments before it are "positional only": https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-does-the-slash-in-the-parameter-list-of-a-function-mean-in-python . Meaning, you can not do `math.pow(x=2, y=3)`

Comment: Also, where do you see this?  When I do `>help(pow))`, I get: `pow(base, exp, mod=None)
`

Comment: @Cargo23 pow vs math.pow

Comment: @Cargo23 use `help(math.pow)`. This doesn't show up on the builtin not stdlib functions.