# what is the meaning of / in the help function in python 3.5.1

Tags: python-3.x

I have updated my python from 3.3.2 to 3.5.1 a few days ago, and the other day by doing help in some function I found something strange, a `/` in the firm of some of the functions, for example:

in 3.3.2

```
>>> help(len)
Help on built-in function len in module builtins:

len(...)
    len(object) -> integer

    Return the number of items of a sequence or mapping.

>>>
```

now in 3.5.1

```
>>> help(len)
Help on built-in function len in module builtins:

len(obj, /)
    Return the number of items in a container.

>>>
```

what is the meaning of this `/`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slash means the end of the "positional only parameters", as better explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735311/python-what-does-the-slash-mean-in-the-output-of-helprange) previous answer.