# Construct defaultdict by passing default_factory as named parameter

Tags: python, defaultdict

I get some strange behaviour of `colletions.defaultdict`:

```
import collections

c1 = collections.defaultdict(str)
c1['new']  # Works!

c2 = collections.defaultdict(default_factory=str)
c2['new']  # Raises KeyError...
```

Why raises `c2` a KeyError?

Sometimes I like naming parameter because I think it increases readability.

First I thought maybe python does not allow me to pass the parameter by naming it and puts my `default_factory` parameter to the kwargs, so I checked:

```
def func(first, **kwargs):
    print(first)
    print(kwargs)

func(first='one', second='two')
```

This outputs:

```
one
{'second': 'two'}
```

So this is not the case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `default_factory` parameter of the `defaultdict` constructor is positional-only and doesn't really have a name. If you try to pass it by name, you are just passing a completely unrelated keyword argument. Since keyword arguments to the `defaultdict` constructor are interpreted as its initial contents, your dict starts out having a single key `"default_factory"` whose value is the `str` type object.

To understand how this works, imagine a function like this:

```
def func(*args, **kwds):
    (default_factory,) = args
    for k, v in kwds.items():
        print(k, v)  # do something with keys and values
```

If the documentation of this function were to name the positional argument `default_factory`, that might be a correct description of its *meaning*, but it would be misleading if it implied that one could pass it as a keyword argument.

Some built-in functions are like that because it is very easy to define positional-only arguments in CPython C code. With `defaultdict`, it is by design, to allow literally *any* string key to be used as the part of initial content, without having an exception for a key that happens to be named `default_factory`.

Comment: I think it might help to add that defaultdict is a built-in class and is not defined in Python, hence it can have a positional-only argument.

Comment: @AlexHall Your original comment had a point, so I amended the answer. I don't think it's necessary to stress `defaultdict` being built-in because the same effect can be achieved in pure Python (which the answer now demonstrates).

Comment: Cool, I didn't realise you could make positional-only arguments in Python. Also nice tuple unpacking trick to get exactly one argument.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me getting something fundamental about python in my head. This was driving me nuts. Probably, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is a misleading here. But no, just read more carefully :-)

Comment: @marsl Yes, the `func([arg])` syntax is a hint (albeit subtle) that `arg` is a positional parameter which is optional, rather than the standard Python's either-positional-or-keyword parameter.

Comment: Is there any what someone could know this from the documentation?

Comment: @user48956 The [documentation for Python 3.9+](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) says `defaultdict(default_factory=None, /[, ...])`, meaning that `default_factory` is a positional-only argument (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735311/what-does-the-slash-mean-in-help-output).