# The slash in the doc string

Tags: python

Here it is the beginning of, e.g., the doc string for the `sum` builtin

> Signature: sum(iterable, start=0, /)

What does the slash, "/", stand for?

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735311/python-what-does-the-slash-mean-in-the-output-of-helprange