# Where is binascii really stored?

Tags: python

whilst digging into encoding/decoding, I found the following part in binascii.py:

```
def a2b_base64(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
""" Decode a line of base64 data. """
    pass
```

From my naive understanding, this is implemented as C somewhere else. Is this in the python.exe itself or am I missing something?

Comment: Your posted code snippet does nothing

Comment: The Python library **has no `binascii.py` file**. Are you looking at something else, like stub files for autocompletion in an IDE perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I seem to have been looking at the stub file whilst 'over-using' CTRL+B in pycharm. How does python know where the following line is then? return binascii.a2b_base64(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *no `binascii.py` file* in the Python standard library. The `binascii` module in Python is entirely written in C; it's implemented in the [`Modules/binascii.c` source file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/binascii.c).

When Python is installed on a system, available as a [shared library object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries), so as a `.so` or `.dll` file in a `lib/pythonx.x/lib-dynload` directory somewhere.

What you found instead is a *stub file*, to aid an IDE in introspection and autocompletion tasks. Such a file is needed because extension modules written in C usually are not introspectable, you can't always use the normal [introspection techniques](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) to figure out what arguments a function written in a compiled language will accept.

Note that such files are slowly becoming obsolete as more and more code in the standard library is being converted to using the new [argument clinic system](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/clinic.html), which enables introspection support. The `binascii` module has been updated to use the AC syntax starting in Python 3.4, so you could ask the module directly:

```
>>> import inspect, binascii
>>> inspect.signature(binascii.a2b_base64)
<Signature (data, /)>
```

The function accepts a single positional-only argument named `data` (see [Python: What does the slash mean in the output of help(range)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735311/python-what-does-the-slash-mean-in-the-output-of-helprange) for an explanation for what the `/` in the signature means or what *positional only* means).

Comment: Absolutely great reply. Thanks so much!