# What does self and / mean in python 3.7?

Tags: python, methods, self, python-3.7

When using help function on some method, I get a short text describing that method. In the first line, most of the time it says:

"method name" (self, iterable, /).

Can anyone tell me what does self and / mean for that method?

Comment: And also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735311/python-what-does-the-slash-mean-in-the-output-of-helprange

Comment: Short version: Everything before the forward slash is passable only positionally (or in the case of `self`, implicitly), not by keyword.