# What makes hex() work properly even if the input is a non integer number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

According to the python `help(hex)` call, the function `hex()` can only receive an integer. But now I realize that it can also receive other types of numbers and I'm curious to know about what feature of python or its modules makes this possible.

The Python console below is of version 3.8 but I received the same output of `hex()` on 2.7.

```
>>> hex(0o20)
'0x10'
>>> hex(0b10000)
'0x10'
>>> hex(16)
'0x10'
>>> help(hex)
Help on built-in function hex in module builtins:

hex(number, /)
    Return the hexadecimal representation of an integer.

    >>> hex(12648430)
    '0xc0ffee'
>>>
```

PD: What does the forward slash on `hex(number, /)` mean? I tried adding two arguments to the function call but the return states that `hex()` can only receive one argument.

Comment: All the examples you've shown are different ways of entering an integer in Python.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735311/what-does-the-slash-mean-in-help-output

Comment: The slash means that you can't pass the preceding arguments by name, only by position. Initially this was a documentation convention, as of Python 3.8 it's become available for use in code.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [syntax for supported radicals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals), you can see that all your examples in the question are of integers.

For example:

> This proposal is to use a "0o" prefix with either uppercase or lowercase "o" for octal, and a "0b" prefix with either uppercase or lowercase "b" for binary.

Comment: Uh, while that *might* still be true today, that's the documentation from over 19 years ago (June 22, 2001). Not the best choice :-)

Comment: Actually it's not true anymore. That's lacking the binary literal and the octal literal with `0o` prefix. Making your "Therefore..." wrong.

Comment: @superbrain Yep, thanks for the correction. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Hmm, no, you still link to the same outdated page, the quote you show isn't on that page, and it's talking about a *proposal* only (and it doesn't say it's about ints).

Comment: Still phrased as a proposal, one needs to go to the page to see that that is a PEP, maybe one that was accepted and implemented like that and that that's still valid (it's from 2007 and is for Python 3.0, after all). I'd just use the current documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals).

Comment: @superbrain Thanks, added. BTW, I know the rep's not a big deal, but if you answer your comment, I'll happily upvote it.

Comment: Well now the quote and the link text again don't match the link :-). I wouldn't have much more to offer in an answer, I'd just fix the quote and link text.