# TypeError: TextIOWrapper.seek() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-io

I wanted to seek to the start of the file of to write from the start.
In the documentation of python 3.9 [io.IOBase.seek](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) it is displayed seek has a parameter "whence" yet an error is being displayed:

> TypeError: TextIOWrapper.seek() takes no keyword arguments

my code is:

```py
with open("t.txt",'a+') as f:
    f.seek(0,)
    print(f.readlines())
    f.seek(0,whence=0)
    f.write("12\n23\n32")
```

I have use "a+" as I want to preserve the contains of the file when it is opened as well edit later.

I wanted to edit the contains from the start that's why I used whence = 0, as it would help me edit from start of the stream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, it's a little bit weird.

Take a look at `help(f.seek)`:

```
Help on built-in function seek:

seek(cookie, whence=0, /) method of _io.TextIOWrapper instance
```

Note the `/` slash. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24735582/8431111

It says "no keywords, please!".

You can specify `f.seek(0)`, or `f.seek(0, 0)`.
You just can't name that 2nd parameter `whence`.
It is helpful documentation in the signature,
but you can't name it in the call.

Comment: I had read issues raised regarding this same in older python version on github, there '/' was mentioned but I couldn't get it that time. Thanks for helping out.