# discord.py new timeout - positional-only arguments error

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to create a timeout command with the new timeout function [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=timeout#discord.Member.timeout)

My code:

```
@commands.command()
async def timeout(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, time, reason, /):
  await member.timeout(until=datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(time)), reason=reason)
```

I get this error:

`TypeError: timeout() got some positional-only arguments passed as keyword arguments: 'until'`

I did a research on positional-only arguments, but no luck. Any fix?

Comment: This video will explain this in detail: [Positional-only and keyword-only arguments in Python](https://youtu.be/R8-oAqCgHag). That channel generally produces a ton of helpful Python content, not just this one video.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the slash mean in help() output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735311/what-does-the-slash-mean-in-help-output)

Comment: Found the solution, ty brat!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, here is the working command!

```py
@commands.command()
async def timeout(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, time, /, reason):
  await member.timeout(datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(time)), reason=reason)
```