# Why can't I pass the default_factory argument in collections.defaultdict as a keyword argument?

Tags: python, default-value, keyword-argument, defaultdict

If I first do

```python
from collections import defaultdict
```

then doing

```python
defaultdict(lambda: "Default value")[7]
```

yields `'Default value'`. However, instead doing

```python
defaultdict(default_factory=lambda: "Default value")[7]
```

results in

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [28], line 1
----> 1 defaultdict(default_factory=lambda: "Default value")[7]
```

but according to the [`defaultdict` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), the first argument is `default_factory`, so the two statements should be equivalent. So why do they behave differently?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735311/what-does-the-slash-mean-in-help-output

Comment: It's not entirely obvious from the documentation, but the `/` following the parameter indicates that all the preceding parameters are positional-only, disallowing keyword arguments from setting them.

Comment: The reason it doesn't accept it as a keyword argument is because it wishes to allow *arbitrary* keyword arguments to describe members of the dictionary. If you write `dict(default_factory=1)`, that creates `{'default_factory': 1}`. `defaultdict` does the same, but if it allowed passing the default factory by keyword, and you did `defaultdict(lambda: "default", default_factory=1)` to specifically create it with that key, it would see it as the same argument being passed twice.